# Mutate dataframes by matching ids in r

Tags: r, plyr, dplyr, mutated

I have three data frames:

df1:

```
id score1
1   50
2   23
3   40
4   68
5   82
6   38
```

df2:

```
id score2
1   33
2   23
4   64
5   12
6   32
```

df3:

```
id score3
1   50
2   23
3   40
4   68
5   82
```

I want to mutate the three scores to a dataframe like this, using NA to denote the missing value

```
id score1 score2 score3
1   50     33     50
2   23     23     23
3   40     NA     40
4   68     64     68
5   82     12     82
6   38     32     NA
```

Or like this, deleting the NA values:

```
id score1 score2 score3
1   50     33     50
2   23     23     23
4   68     64     68
5   82     12     82
```

However, mutate (in dplyer) does not take different length. So I can not mutate. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
  Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by='id'), list(df1, df2, df3))
  #   id score1 score2 score3
  #1  1     50     33     50
  #2  2     23     23     23
  #3  4     68     64     68
  #4  5     82     12     82
```

If you have many dataset object names with pattern 'df' followed by number

```
  Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by='id'), mget(paste0('df',1:3)))
```

Or instead of `paste0('df', 1:3)`, you can use `ls(pattern='df\\d+')` as commented by @DavidArenburg

Comment: Thanks! @akrun. I do not know the ‘reduce’ function before :)